# What is the recommended page size for GETting sales orders through REST API calls?

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api

I am trying to make a GET call to the Magento 2 REST API to get all the sales orders. What is the recommended page size I should be using? Is there any upper limit on the page size?

Comment: "Is there any upper limit on the page size" i don't think so. but use minimal to speed up  process.

Comment: It really depends on your app... pick a lower number to start with (eg. 20). if you need to just increase it later.. you could also provide a dropdown where the user can select the preferred amount.

Answer (score 1):

Page size is not limited by Magento. However, at some Page sizes your Magento instance will start running out of memory and will not be able to process the request. The limit obviously depends on your hardware.

There are two options:

1. Implement proper pagination on your application with configurable
   page size
2. Try "Infinite scroll". This approach may not work
   perfectly on instances with frequently created orders, because
   Magento REST API does not support cursor-based pagination (which is designed for such scenarios)